# Storage of ASCII values of a string in an integral array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, ascii

How can i store **ASCII** values of a **string** in an **integral array** and not **print** them in ***C***?
For example: I input "*ABab*" and i have an array of a[4] then how can i store a[0]=67, a[1]=66, a[2]=97, a[3]=98?

Comment: Strings are already stored as arrays of ASCII values. If you have a problem, please post your [mcve].

Comment: Could you explain the _"and not print them"_ part? If you don't want to print them, just don't print them.

Comment: In a question like this, you should try something yourself, and then ask about the code you wrote, if it doesn't work.

Comment: In C there is no fancy way. Just use a simple for loop and assign values from one array to other one-by-one.

Comment: Note that the code for `’A’` is usually 65, not 67.

Comment: Also note that in source code, "ABab" is an _array_ of 5 characters because a string literal is implicitly ␀-terminated. When treating it as _text_, it has 4 characters because the terminator is not part of the text.

Answer (score 2):

It's already stored as you mention: a string is an array of `char` and a `char` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know that computers work on "*bi*nary digi*t*s (*bit*s)", so did you already ask yourself how the computer would store a character *at all*?

The answer is: That's what *character encodings* like ASCII are meant for: They assign a unique number to every character and the number is what gets stored!

As C should work on virtually any machine/system/OS, it doesn't specify which encoding is used for the characters, it just specifies a few properties this encoding must fulfill. ASCII only consists of 128 different codes (the amount that can be represented by 7 bits), so nowadays, larger encodings than ASCII are used, but with a probability *very close to 1*, your system uses an encoding that *includes* ASCII (very often this would be UTF-8).

So, as already commented, when you read characters in an array of `char`, you **already** end up with the ASCII values stored there. `char` is the smallest integer type in C and corresponds to a byte -- and a *byte* is exactly the amount of bits needed to store the representation of a character. This is almost always 8 bits, but larger values are allowed by the C standard.

If you want to *print* a number, you have to convert it to decimal places and convert these to the (ASCII) codes of the characters `0` to `9`. Of course, C already has a function doing this for you: `printf()` with a suitable *format string*. To print the decimal value of a byte/`char`, you can simply do:

```
char c = 'A';
printf("%hhu", (unsigned char)c);
```

`u` is the conversion specifier for an unsigned integer, `hh` modifies the length of the argument to `char`, and you cast your `char` to `unsigned char` because C allows `char` to be *either* signed *or* unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to copy elements of a string into an array of the type `int`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h?

int main( void )
{
    char *s = "ABab";
    int a[4];
    const size_t N = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

    size_t i = 0;

    for (; i < N && s[i] != '\0'; i++) a[i] = s[i];
    while (i != N) a[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
65 66 97 98
```

If you need to output a character array as integers instead of their symbol representations then you can just write

```
#include <stdio.h?

int main( void )
{
    char *s = "ABab";

    for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) printf("%d ", s[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that the type `char` can behave either as the type `signed char` or `unsigned char`. If you want to store or output characters as unsigned values you should write in the first program

```
for (; i < N && s[i] != '\0'; i++) a[i] = ( unsigned char )s[i];
```

and in the second program

```
for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) printf("%d ", ( unsigned char )s[i]);
```

That is you need to cast explicitly `char` to `unsigned char`.